# IBM Cloud Functions Service can't retrieve a list of databases on trying to create a new binding to a Cloudant action

Tags: ibm-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a sequence for documents uploading. I created the Cloudant instance, database in it and IAM and legacy credentials. Suddenly, I receive an error retrieving a list of databases when I try to bind a Cloudant action to a Cloudant instance. What do I check to resolve this issue?
[Failed to retrieve a list of databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiwQy.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
You can choose Instance > Input your own credentials instead.
Fill your username, password. Host can be found in Cloudant > Service credentials.